# Deformation of the cylinder

Tags: elasticity

There is given a cylinder with fixed side surface. On one base is being rendered constant pressure $p$, so cylinder cambers

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the form of cambering. The problem is that height of the cylinder can't be neglected, so one can't use results for mambranes from elasticy theory.

My approach was in proposing that this form will be close to the form of cambered parallelepiped in simillar conditions rotated around z axis:

[image]

Even if this proposition is right, I didn't succeed in calculations for parallelepiped, so I'm asking help with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well defined solution to this problem. Look into table 11.2 case 2f in [Roark formulas for Stress and Strain](http://materiales.azc.uam.mx/gjl/Clases/MA10_I/Roark's%20formulas%20for%20stress%20and%20strain.pdf).

The general deformation shape is given by:

> [image: Circular Plate Shape]

Solving the governing equations for a special case is *not trivial*. But the theory of circular plate deflection is well established and with some more searching you might be able to find the equation you want.

Comment: Wow, what a useful (if rather boring) reference!

Comment: The center should not have slope to it, and with free inside the inside lip can curl down. An infinitesimal connection in the middle is a better idealization.